# Offsetting animation

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I have grouped together (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) aome animated meshes (9 of them) and I have used the graph editor (F-curve modifier) to cycle them through my animation but is there a way to offset them so they move at different intervals to create a more realistic effect. Cheers.

Comment: Are you wanting to offset the animation within a group instance? This is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Animate one of the objects. Then select all other objects, selecting the first animated object last (so that it's active) and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> > Animation Data. This will make all those objects use the same "Action" for animation. Then in the NLA editor you can move these actions around per object to offset the animation.

Seems tedious, so there's probably an addon that does most of this stuff for you (?)

Answer (score 8):

Another way. You can animate one of the objects, make it parent for the second, the second parent of the third....in the Properties Editor (Object Tab) of each child, check the Slow Parent option in the Relation Extras panel and type number in "offset".
An example: [slow parent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbSUJcsem8c)

Full tutorial and more: [other link](http://blendersushi.blogspot.fr/2013/03/random-many-of-blender-hidden-features.html)

Comment: Not quite animation offset, but still pretty damn cool.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use AreWo and let the addon duplicate the object, if they're different you can change the mesh data after you're done. https://www.blenderdiplom.com/en/downloads/537-arewo-gui-a-detailed-description.html